# Datatable v-for to produce checkbox or input based on data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Wondering how I can get my datatable to build a column that produces either a checkbox or input based on a value from data. This is the what I have but I have a good feeling there is a way better way of doing this.

```
<div v-for=”shirt in shirts”>
   <div v-if=”stock.shirts < 2”>
       <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </div>
  <div v-else>
       <td><input type="text"> of {{ props.item.shirts }}</td>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is stock.shirts an overall stock of every shirt you have? or does each shirt in shirts have its own stock level? if so, you'd probably want shirt.stock in the v-if

Comment: Yes each stock has its own level of shirts. If there is more than 1 shirt available, I am trying to display an input, but if only one, display a checkbox in that column for that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce your if clause

```
<td v-for=”shirt in shirts”><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td v-else><input type="text"> of {{ props.item.shirts }}</td>
```

[vue docs - Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

or you can use dynamic components, like so:

```
<template>
   <td>
      <component :is="component" :data="passthroughdata" />
   </td>
</template>

//...

props: ["value", "passthroughdata"],
data() {

  return {

    component: {}
  },
},
watch: {
 value:{
   handler: async function(){
      try{
        await import(`./components/${valueBasedComponent}/index.vue`)
        this.component = () => import(`./${valueBasedComponent}/index.vue`)
      } catch() {

        this.component = () => import(`./${someDefaultComponent}/index.vue`)
      }
   },
   // immediate: true
 }
}
```

[vue docs - Dynamic & Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: Definitely interested in Dynamic & Async Components. Will look into that. How would the v-for account for the value? Wouldnt I need a v-if to check every row to determine the checkbox or input?

Comment: Ah wait, I see the link now you posted below that one as well. Thanks

Comment: `<DynamicCell v-for="item in items" :value="item.celltype" :passthrough="item" />`